# Angular, TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i'm trying to make a custom filter pipe by following this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVTNaYBVP88), but i got error that said `Angular, TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`. I already imported the pipe to `app.module.ts` and also declared it in `declaration`. Can anyone help me with this error?

```html
<form id="filter">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="term" [(ngModel)]="term" placeholder="filter by name" />
</form>

<tr *ngFor="let product of productList | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 1, currentPage: p } | filter: term">
  <td>{{product.prdName}}</td>
  <td>{{product.prdCat}}</td>
  <td>{{product.prdSup}}</td>
</tr>
```

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})


transform(prdName: any, term: any): any {
    if (term === undefined) return prdName;

    return prdName.filter(function(Product) {
      return Product.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
    })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this :

```
transform(items: any, term: any): any {
    if (term === undefined) return items;

    return items.filter(function(Product) {
        return Product.prdName.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the attribute called 'name' or 'prdName' (the one you used in the template is 'prdName')?

```
transform(values, args) {
    values.filter(
      product => product.prdName.toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase())
    )
}
```

Comment: it is prdName in component.html and component.ts

Comment: @WiraXie I have updated my answer with some changes I guess will make your code better.