# Angular 4 pipe Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: angular, filter, pipe

I have implemented the following filter/pipe to capitalize first letter, imported in module.ts etc.

pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({name: 'capitalize'})
export class CapitalizePipe implements PipeTransform {

   transform(str:any) {

     var splitStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {

        splitStr[i] = splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
        splitStr[i].substring(1);     
    }
    // Directly return the joined string
    return splitStr.join(' '); 
   }
 }
```

Everything work fine, except when I use it in this expression, I get - **Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined**

```
 {{messageItem?.cc && messageItem?.cc[0]?.name | capitalize}}
```

Comment: this is async, so pipe is executed before data has arrived, thus `undefined`

Comment: is there any way to fix it?

Comment: try to use impure pipe instead of pure pipe ... use `pure: false`

Comment: why did you updated the question with the answer? Now your question/error log makes no sense

Comment: True, updated back, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular, TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346800/angular-typeerror-cannot-read-property-tolowercase-of-undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a null/undefined check in your pipe to check if the string is null before calling `.toLowerCase`

```
if (str === undefined) return [];
```

Comment: hello sajeetharan..... ! can you please go to this link ....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48804782/unable-to-filter-the-data-in-the-matselect-accessed-using-the-http-get-in-angu.... even  I am facing the same error......

Answer (score 0):

Pipe execute initialy as null since this is async. u need to handle the `undefined` variable

```
var splitStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ') || []
```