# Unable to filter the data in the (MatSelect) accessed using the Http get in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created a simple Angular app using Angular Material with an input field and a select.

In my select I am accessing data using HTTP get request from `accountdetails.json` which is placed in my assets folder.

I have applied search filter for the select, but when i type the required option, the list does not get filtered.

`account.component.ts`:

```ts
import {Component, ViewChild, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import { AccountdetailService } from '../accountdetail.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.scss']
})

export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

  filtertext: string;
  departments: any;
  acc_id='': number;

  constructor( private accdetailservice: AccountdetailService ) { }


  /* Table Starts here
  ---------------------- */

  displayedColumns1 = ['acc_id', 'acc_des', 'investigator', 'CPC','location','dept_id','deptdesc'];
  dataSource1= new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);


  applyFilter(filterValue: any) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource1.filter = filterValue;
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.accdetailservice.accountdetails()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.departments = data;
      // Add this row
      this.dataSource1.data = data;
    });
  }


  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.dataSource1.paginator = this.paginator;
    }

    @ViewChild('form') form;
    reset() {
      this.form.nativeElement.reset()
    }
  }

  const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [];
```

`account.component.html`:

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary" style="width:100%"> WELCOME </mat-toolbar><br/>

<form #form>      
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> Account ID</td>
      <td>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Account ID" [(value)]="acc_id">
        </mat-form-field><br/>
      </td>

      &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
      <td>Department</td>
      <td>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select style="min-width: 200px;" placeholder="Type to search" [(value)]="department">
            <input class="input1" matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="filtertext"         (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let dep of departments  | filter:filtertext  " [value]="dep.department" >
              {{ dep.department }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<br/><br/>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="reset()">Reset </button>

<!-- Table starts here -->

<mat-card>
  <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource1">

      <!-- Account No. Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="acc_id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Account ID. </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.acc_id}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Account Description Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="acc_des">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Account Description </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.acc_des}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Investigator Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="investigator">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Investigator </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.investigator}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Account CPC Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="CPC">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Account CPC </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.CPC}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Location Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="location">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Location </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.location}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>


      <!-- Client Dept ID Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="dept_id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DeptID </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.dept_id}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>


      <!-- Dept Description Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="deptdesc">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Dept Description </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.deptdesc}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>


      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns1" ></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns1;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>

    <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [pageSize]="10"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
    </mat-paginator>
  </div>
</mat-card>
```

`filter.pipe.ts`:

```ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(departments1: any, filtertext: string) {
    if(filtertext=== undefined){
      return departments1;
    } else if(departments1)
    {
       return departments1.filter(function(department){
         return department.value.toLowerCase().includes(filtertext.toLowerCase());

       })   
    }
  }
}
```

`app.module.ts`:

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import { AppMaterialModule } from './app-material.module';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './account/account.component';

import { AccountdetailService } from './accountdetail.service';



import './rxjs-operators';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AccountComponent ,
    FilterPipe      
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppMaterialModule,
    FormsModule ,
    HttpModule   
  ],
  providers: [ AccountdetailService ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Lastly, I have applied a reset button for the form. The `Account ID` input gets reset after i click the `Reset` button, but the `Department` select field doesn't reset.

Comment: please can you assist me in this...

Comment: when I am trying to filter the dropdown I am getting this error ...Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer to this..

### I modified my filter.pipe.ts as below

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, filtertext?: any): any {

        if (!value) return null;
        if (!filtertext) return value;

        filtertext = filtertext.toLowerCase();

        return value.filter(function (item: any) {
            return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(filtertext);
        });
    }
}
```